# Enabling others to run anonymous without asking for trust every time?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, authorization

I've been migrating more and more to using Google Apps to publish scripts for various tools I make.  Until recently, it has worked great; however, recent scripts that I have been making have been putting warnings out for users every time they access the page.

[image: Trust example image]

Now I'm aware of the fact that Google did, over the summer, make a [change](https://venturebeat.com/2017/07/18/google-rolls-out-new-warnings-for-g-suite-and-apps-script/) to their verification process.  I actually went through, as far as I can tell, the process of getting the app verified, including getting verification for the script via the process on the dashboard there.  However, the warning remains, and comes up every time.

To try to prevent users from having to log in (it's a database for tournament information, so in theory it only accesses my own Fusion Tables/spreadsheets), I have it set up to run as me, but anyone can access, including anonymous.
[image: Settings I use for deployment]

So long story short, does anyone know a way to get that trust message to go away (or alternatively, a better workaround)?  I've been working with these scripts for some time, as it was a great way to work for free, but I'm stumped on this trust thing.

Comment: I have this same exact question! I have a Google script that I've deployed as a web app, and until today (at least as far as I know), it was great. Now, it's always popping up a dialog: `Do you know ____@gmail.com?
warning This application was created by ____. Only use applications from developers you trust. [Back to Safety] [Trust App]`. What the hell. I don't want to annoy my clients with this step.

Comment: Your question is "off topic" to Stack Overflow.  It's a good question, but it's not a programming question.  It's better to post your question on the Google Community for Apps Script.  [Link - Google Apps Script](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/102471985047225101769)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web app asking user to login, even though its been deployed to be used by "Anyone, even anonymous"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58358716/web-app-asking-user-to-login-even-though-its-been-deployed-to-be-used-by-anyon)