# Web app asking user to login, even though its been deployed to be used by "Anyone, even anonymous"

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I've deployed a script to be used as a web app that can be accessed by "Anyone, even anonymous" and yet, if a user has not logged into a gmail account on a particular browser, its asking them to login.

Here's my manifest file -

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "ANYONE_ANONYMOUS",
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

To replicate the problem, you can visit the following link by logging out of your gmail accounts (or in a browser that does not have your gmail sign in) -

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyayXeY_LGm7sy-J1VGvg7wfqOZYonZmKphS0F4Qz4jLZ336qsR/exec/test*

**it is required that you not change the pathInfo of the URL*

Current behavior -

1. When signed in: You will be redirected to https://www.google.com/
2. When signed out: You'll be asked to login to your Google acc.

I'm building (or rather, though I already had built) a [URL shortener service using Apps Script](https://github.com/schoraria911/gas-url-shortener) and oddly, it is not asking users to login when accessed from a custom domain (an iframe embedded in https://tmt.pw) but it is asking them to login once they shorten the URL and try visiting the shortened URL.

The original resources are all available here -

- The entire folder on my [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SuHsBLbSYm5dSnp3NeGmUOTnC9NPqEje?usp=sharing)
- A Spreadsheet that acts as the [datasource](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xPs4Ht-3PVBGgdNSxyN3p2F5TtOifgvunrEvYaiu_A4/edit?usp=sharing)
- Finally, [the script](https://script.google.com/d/1wdNu632PfJNv0iCCNLjA-9nARemz7DLcK28Lio6YdVNMP3iEtOUtR4_R/edit?usp=sharing) itself

I've tested this on Chrome, Safari and Firefox (all on a Mac) and they all exhibit the same behavior.

I'm guessing this is something very fundamental and all I want is the web app to not ask users to login, given that it has been instructed to execute even for an anonymous user.

## Edit note1

The script has some business with a Spreadsheet as well and so I tried making the sheet publicly editable by everyone (anyone on the internet) and it still didn't work.

## Edit note2

Was using 1 private function (with an `_` at the end of the function name) & have stopped doing that in my script - still no change; problem persists.

Comment: Is it asking them to login or simply to give the script permission to run. If it’s the latter then I think the only way to avoid that is to have it execute as you

Comment: @Cooper - thanks for pitching in. Its simply asking to login (not to give script any permissions) and the script is already being executed as me (user deploying the script).

Comment: If you go to https://tmt.pw and view the source code, it too is the apps script being invoked from inside an iframe - no permission is being asked here. Its only when trying to go to the aforementioned long URL is when the user is being asked to login to their Google acc.

Comment: Please refer me to `pathInfo` property documentation.

Comment: `/exec` is deployed as Anyone even anonymous. `/exec/whatever`  isn't accessible by anonymous users. This also explains why when embedded in a iframe, it doesn't ask for login, because you're embedding the `/exec` url and not the `/exec/*` url. I guess this is also why `e.pathInfo` is undocumented.

Comment: @TheMaster - you're correct :) Jasper Duizendstra and I got on a Hangouts call and help me sort the whole thing out. I'm switching my code back to using `e.queryString` and rolling back on using `pathInfo` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the parameter in the path after the /exec triggers the login after the redirect. Using the [queryString](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters) will probably work.

Comment: Thanks, Jasper. You were truly of great help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I was hunting down a similar issue. Finally found my culprit.

In my case I still had a /dev link leftover from testing being used in one of my html files.